# Harddisks appear as ata in ubuntu server 20.04 and as scsi in server 23.10 -- zpool won't recognise disks

Tags: server, hard-drive, zfs

I decided to make a fresh OS-install for my home-server. I attached a new SSD for the root OS and installed ubuntu server 23.10. After installation and first boot, some installed software etc., I tried to import my ZFS Pool consisting of 5 HDDs (`zpool import` and `zpool import -f`)

this returns the following:

```
 pool: pool
     id: 9803748964127808070
  state: UNAVAIL
status: The pool was last accessed by another system.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-EY
 config:

        pool                                          UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
          raidz2-0                                    UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
            sdf                                       ONLINE
            ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0D2HWW2  UNAVAIL
            sde                                       ONLINE
            ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0D4XY9K  UNAVAIL
            ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N0D8KYWT  UNAVAIL
```

I then attached the old SSD with my working Ubuntu Server 20.04 (initially 16.04 -- then continuously upgraded... always has been loyal to me). There, the pool loads without problems.

The problem lies, I guess, in different initialization of the disks. The unavailable disks (`ata-WDC_***`) are in fact available in 23.10 but as `scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68E_WD-WMC4N0D4XY9K` etc.

I am puzzled: why the different naming in 23.10? And further, why are two disks in the pool suddenly initialized as `sdf` and `sde`? Originally, all disks in the pool were added by their `/dev/disk/by-id/`.

//Edit:
Output of `ls -la /dev/disk/by-id`

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-0ATA_GIGABYTE_GP-GSTF_SN232808922472 -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-0ATA_GIGABYTE_GP-GSTF_SN232808922472-part1 -> ../../sdf1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-0ATA_GIGABYTE_GP-GSTF_SN232808922472-part2 -> ../../sdf2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-0ATA_GIGABYTE_GP-GSTF_SN232808922472-part3 -> ../../sdf3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-1ATA_GIGABYTE_GP-GSTFS31480GNTD_SN232808922472 -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-1ATA_GIGABYTE_GP-GSTFS31480GNTD_SN232808922472-part1 -> ../../sdf1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-1ATA_GIGABYTE_GP-GSTFS31480GNTD_SN232808922472-part2 -> ../../sdf2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-1ATA_GIGABYTE_GP-GSTFS31480GNTD_SN232808922472-part3 -> ../../sdf3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-350014ee26452f8bf -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-350014ee26452f8bf-part1 -> ../../sde1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-350014ee26452f8bf-part9 -> ../../sde9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-350014ee2bd4d1804 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-350014ee2bd4d1804-part1 -> ../../sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-350014ee2bd4d1804-part9 -> ../../sdd9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-350014ee604c7074e -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-350014ee604c7074e-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-350014ee604c7074e-part9 -> ../../sdc9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-350014ee6af71860b -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-350014ee6af71860b-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-350014ee6af71860b-part9 -> ../../sda9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-350014ee6af719205 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-350014ee6af719205-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-350014ee6af719205-part9 -> ../../sdb9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_GIGABYTE_GP-GSTF_SN232808922472 -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_GIGABYTE_GP-GSTF_SN232808922472-part1 -> ../../sdf1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_GIGABYTE_GP-GSTF_SN232808922472-part2 -> ../../sdf2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_GIGABYTE_GP-GSTF_SN232808922472-part3 -> ../../sdf3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFAX-68J_WD-WX52D409RASJ -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFAX-68J_WD-WX52D409RASJ-part1 -> ../../sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFAX-68J_WD-WX52D409RASJ-part9 -> ../../sdd9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68E_WD-WCC4N7FDCRUN -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68E_WD-WCC4N7FDCRUN-part1 -> ../../sde1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68E_WD-WCC4N7FDCRUN-part9 -> ../../sde9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68E_WD-WMC4N0D2HWW2 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68E_WD-WMC4N0D2HWW2-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68E_WD-WMC4N0D2HWW2-part9 -> ../../sdc9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68E_WD-WMC4N0D4XY9K -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68E_WD-WMC4N0D4XY9K-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68E_WD-WMC4N0D4XY9K-part9 -> ../../sdb9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68E_WD-WMC4N0D8KYWT -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68E_WD-WMC4N0D8KYWT-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EFRX-68E_WD-WMC4N0D8KYWT-part9 -> ../../sda9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 wwn-0x50014ee26452f8bf -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 wwn-0x50014ee26452f8bf-part1 -> ../../sde1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 wwn-0x50014ee26452f8bf-part9 -> ../../sde9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 wwn-0x50014ee2bd4d1804 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 wwn-0x50014ee2bd4d1804-part1 -> ../../sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 wwn-0x50014ee2bd4d1804-part9 -> ../../sdd9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 wwn-0x50014ee604c7074e -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 wwn-0x50014ee604c7074e-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 wwn-0x50014ee604c7074e-part9 -> ../../sdc9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 wwn-0x50014ee6af71860b -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 wwn-0x50014ee6af71860b-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 wwn-0x50014ee6af71860b-part9 -> ../../sda9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Jan  9 09:11 wwn-0x50014ee6af719205 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 wwn-0x50014ee6af719205-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jan  9 09:11 wwn-0x50014ee6af719205-part9 -> ../../sdb9
```

Comment: Please list output of `ls -la /dev/disk/by-id` in your question.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to force ZFS to scan the `/dev/disks/by-id/` directory for devices, like this:

```
sudo zpool import -f -d /dev/disk/by-id/ pool
```

But this will of course require that all devices are properly present in Ubuntu, which can be checked with `ls -la /dev/disk/by-id`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint. A slightly modified command did the trick: `sudo zpool import -f -d /dev/disk/by-id`. However, the devices listed are not `ata-WDC*` but different designations `wwn-*`. Nonetheless, a scrub with no errors and everything successfully automounts on boot. Thank you.

Comment: Added `-f` to my answer. 